# Dropzone - Using file upload to attach images for phpmailer

Tags: phpmailer, email-attachments, dropzone.js

I'm trying to create a form in which the user can add (Upload) some images. After "Submit" the form should send an Email with attached files (image/images)

I'm using phpmailer for my form.

**My Question:** Is it possible to send the images as attachments without storing them on the Server, and send directly in  Email with the attached files - I don't want to store user Documents on Server.

Thank You

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The documents will have to be stored temporarly on the server if you plan on supporting sequential uploads. You could on the other side add javascript so that a user uploads all images at once and then your backend sends them via mail.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I'm kind of new to to all this and seems pretty complicated. Any tutorials or similar implementation that you could suggest.?